# Is it necessary to mention unit in vectors, when in $i,j,k$ form?

Tags: kinematics, vectors, velocity, dimensional-analysis, si-units

For example,
If I have a vector:
$$v= 2.0i + 3.0j +8.0k.$$
Is it necessary to put the vector in the form:
v=2.0i+3.0j+8.0k m s-1
Or can I leave it without mentioning the unit?

Answer (score 3):

The units should be mentioned.